# SAS Macro variable resolve issue in datastep

Tags: sas, sas-macro

There are similar named macro variables like temp1,temp2 etc..

temp1=xyz;
temp2=abc;

Now I want to store these macro variable values into dataset.

I tried writing something as below:

```
%let n=2;
data current_data;
do=1 to &n.;
myvalues="&&temp&i.";
run;
```

But its not working.
It seems that i is not getting resolved in the same dataset as it is declared in just like call symput function does.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your desired result here? Do you want an observation for each macro variable?

Comment: Why did you put the data into macro variables in the first place?  Hard to see how you could get a series of macro variables like that without starting with a dataset.  Why not just use the original dataset?

Comment: @Tom : These are the input from the prompt of stored procedure. I give user an option to enter multivalued text, so they enter n number of values, each becomes macro variable of similar name, so I need to read those and put it into dataset. Hope my question is clear to you now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically retrieve the value of a macro variable at run time in a data step use `symget()` function, the reverse of the `call symputx()` function.  You can use `cats()` to help you build the macro variable name from your integer value.

```
data current_data;
  do=1 to &n.;
    length myvalues $200;
    myvalues=symget(cats('temp',i));
    output;
  end;
run;
```

You could use macro logic to generate some wallpaper code.  Note that you must define a macro to use %DO loop.

```
%macro expand;
   data current_data;
     length i 8 myvalues $200;
  %do i=1 %to &n;
     i=&i;
     myvalues="&&temp&i";
     output;
  %end;
   run;
%mend expand;
%expand;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! you made m day :)